# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'appname'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.pom
> - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

React natice developer